# I have a question about past continuous tense 'was buying'

Tags: tense

Here is a sentence I've got on my textbook.

> I **was buying** a new washer because my old one had broken down. I ordered a model that was in stock and available for next-day delivery.

I can't understand how it is possible to use **was buying** in the above sentence, which is really unfamiliar to me.
I think the following sentences is more familiar form to me.

> I **was thinking of buying** a new washer because my old one had broken down.
>
> I **was shopping online** for a new washer because my old one had broken down.
>
> I **decided to buy** a new washer because my old one had broken down.

So, I'd like to know what exactly '**was buying**' means.

Could you let me know why the 'past continuous tense' is used?

Answer (score 2):

> Could you let me know why the 'past continuous tense' is used?

Probably because the sentence is in First Person ("*I* was buying"). When you have a *first person* sentence ("I was buying a new washer"), you can expect the sentences to be written more as if they were dialogue -- as if the character were speaking directly to you, using more informal language than a *third person* sentence ("He was shopping for a new washer.")

In speech, it is very common to use "buying" for the *process* of "shopping for," since there are not necessarily clear boundaries between "shopping for an item" and "purchasing *this* item." (Especially online! You click around, then you start entering in data required to purchase things; the process is not the last instant when you click the last button!)

Further, "buying" and "getting" are often synonymous in context -- "So, I was getting some bras at the department store" is easily translated to "So, I was buying some bras at the department store." This basically says that you left the store with new bras, whereas "I was shopping for some bras" means you *must* have more sentences to indicate whether you purchased any.

Why did your book choose to use first person? I do not know. It is possible that first person sentences looked more "interesting" to the person writing them, and they unconsciously dropped into a more informal pattern of words. It is also possible that it's a deliberate informality, to get students used to the patterns of speech so they won't be confused later when they talk to people.